# android LinearLayout scroll too deep

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have layout which scrolls too high. It scrolls until reaches an end and even scrolls more up until last 4 lines visible.

So my page stays almost without text - it is too high..
There is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<include layout="@layout/title_bar" android:id = "@+id/title"/>
<ScrollView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="360dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    >
<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >

     <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="360dp"/>  

   <!-- <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_span="4"  
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"         
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:text="@string/btn_system_setup"
            />
    </TableRow> --> 


        <RadioGroup android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left">
            <RadioButton 
                    android:id="@+id/test_over_xdsl"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/test_over_xdsl"
                    />
            <RadioButton 
                    android:id="@+id/test_over_shdsl"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/test_over_shdsl"
                    />

            <RadioButton 
                    android:id="@+id/test_over_eth"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/test_over_eth"/>
        </RadioGroup>



    <TableRow
    >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/ip_adress"
            />
        <EditText 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
            android:layout_width="200dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true" 
            android:id="@+id/ip_adress"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi">
        </EditText>

        <TextView  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/netmask"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        />

        <EditText 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:id="@+id/netmask"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"
            android:layout_width="200dp">
        </EditText>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
    >
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/default_gateway"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

        <EditText
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/default_gateway"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"
            android:layout_width="200dp">
        </EditText>

        <TextView  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:paddingLeft="20dp"
             android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/primary_dns"
        />

        <EditText 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/dns_server"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"
            android:layout_width="200dp">
        </EditText>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
    >
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/secondary_dns"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

        <EditText 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/secondary_dns_server"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"
            android:layout_width="200dp">
        </EditText>



    </TableRow>


    <RadioGroup android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
            <RadioButton 
                    android:id="@+id/emulated"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/emulated"
                    />

            <RadioButton 
                    android:id="@+id/through"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/through"/>
        </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup 
            android:id="@+id/dhcp_radiogroup"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
            <RadioButton 
                    android:id="@+id/dhcp_disabled"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/disable_dhcp"
                    android:checked="true"
                    />

            <RadioButton 
                    android:id="@+id/dhcp_enabled"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/enable_dhcp"/>
        </RadioGroup>

    <TableRow android:id = "@+id/start_stop"
                android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/ip_adress_start"
            />
        <EditText 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
            android:layout_width="200dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true" 
            android:id="@+id/ip_adress_start"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi">
        </EditText>

        <TextView  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/ip_adress_end"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        />

        <EditText 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:id="@+id/ip_address_end"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone|flagNoExtractUi"
            android:layout_width="200dp">
        </EditText>

    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
    >
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/change_date_time"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_time"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="200dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />
        <Button 
            android:text="@string/set_time_and_date"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:id="@+id/setTimeButton" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>

    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
    >
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/change_language"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/language"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="200dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />
        <Button 
            android:text="@string/set_time_and_date"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:id="@+id/setLanguageButton" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
    >
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/change_country"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/country"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="200dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />
        <Button 
            android:text="@string/set_time_and_date"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:id="@+id/setCountryButton" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
    >
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/hardware_type"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hardware_type_text"
            android:layout_width="200dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
    >
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/hardware_version"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hardware_version_text"
            android:layout_width="200dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
    >
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/software_version"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />
       <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/software_version_text"
            android:text="@string/the_version"
            android:layout_width="200dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
    >
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/firmware_version"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />
       <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/firmware_version_text"
            android:text="@string/the_version"
            android:layout_width="200dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Now I suppose there will be easy solution suggested.

Comment: http://imagebin.org/226158 is the picture for this case. System did not let me add it.

Comment: why isn't the first LinearLayout closed?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/EFta94tJ contains full layout, stackoverflow doesn't show this xml properly.